Is It possible to implement multiple DataTemplate in TabControl.ContentTemplate?
I am currently migrating a WPF window to MVVM architecture. I have a TabControl that contains four TabItems, all set manually. My goal is to set the values dynamically using a ViewModel class.
I implemented it like this:
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel.Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding TabSelected}"
               Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Padding="0"
               BorderThickness="0"
               IsTabStop="False"
               Grid.RowSpan="2">

       <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
       </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       
       <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:DataGridModel}">
               <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ListViewItemModel}">
               <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                   <ListView.View>
                       <GridView>
                           <GridViewColumn Header="Description" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Description}"/>
                       </GridView>
                   </ListView.View>
               </ListView>
           </DataTemplate>
           <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:CardModel}">
               <StackPanel>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail}" FontSize="14"/>
               </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
       </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
  </TabControl>


But I'm getting the error: "DataTemplate can accept only one child."

Move those datatemplates to TabControl.Resources

Also make yourself familiar with TemplateSelectors - in your case TabControl.ContentTemplateSelector - to automatically switch the used template based on DataContext of the selected item

@SanchoPanza Automatic template selection is already done by means of the DataType property. You would use a DataTemplateSelector only for manual selection of a DataTemplate.

thx @Clemens, very interesting. Seems like I wrote a bunch of unnecessary selectors before today -.-
